# Куда сохраняются временные файлы?

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu постоянно жалуется на нехватку места. Я чищу диски из Windows, и там показывает, что на всех дисках минимум по 3гб свободного места, но когда перезахожу в Убунту - опять пишет, что места нет.

1. Когда я что-то устанавливаю, копируя в терминал команды установки, может быть, после установки эти файлы не удаляются? Где их найти?
2. Как посмотреть, на каком диске установлен сам Убунту? Ставил давно и не помню, поэтому приходится каждый раз перезаходить в Винду и чистить все диски подряд (идиотизм). Какой из всех Убунту стоит, тоже не помню, но версия 15.

---

```
$ df
Файл.система   1K-блоков Использовано Доступно Использовано% Cмонтировано в
udev             4070464            0  4070464            0% /dev
tmpfs             817508         9548   807960            2% /run
/dev/sdb7       10025596      9390132   103140           99% /
tmpfs            4087540           84  4087456            1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120            4     5116            1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4087540            0  4087540            0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs                100            0      100            0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs             817508           64   817444            1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: приложите к вопросу вывод программы `df`. и сообщите, на какие именно ваши действия «Ubuntu постоянно жалуется на нехватку места».

Comment: Добавил то что выдает терминал (тот который ctrl+alt+T) при вводе команды df - если я правильно Вас понял. Жалуется при старте системы и далее при работе приложений - мол осталось мало места и т.д. При 0 байтов начинает вырубать приложения.

Comment: у Вас явно забит под завязку корень. Нужно чистить. Я обычно в таких случаях делаю так `cd / && du * -sh` (команда не быстрая!) и смотрю, где наибольше места. Потом перехожу в папку и снова `du * -sh`. Обычно виновника нахожу быстро. Сейчас скажут, что можно поставить различные утилиты для автоматизации этого, но... у нас же место в корне закончилось. Ничего так просто не поставишь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как посмотреть, на каком диске установлен сам Убунту?

исходя из приведённого вами вывода программы `df` (см. ниже) можно сделать вывод, что в вашем случае используется 7 раздел на втором из блочных устройств: `sdb` — это второй, `sda` — этой первый.

> перезаходить в Винду и чистить все диски подряд

если вы не предпринимали спецмер, то *ms/windows* не увидит содержимого файловой системы, на которой у вас установлен дистрибутив *ubuntu*. для *ms/windows* этот раздел будет выглядеть как «неизвестный» (затрудняюсь дать более точное определение ввиду отсутствия *ms/windows* в доступном мне пространстве).

---

```
$ df
...
/dev/sdb7       10025596      9390132   103140           99% /
...
```

файловая система на разделе sdb7 заполнена почти «под завязку». это единственная файловая система, примонтированная с раздела блочного устройства. так как единственная — это упрощает задачу.

---

для начала сто́ит удалить скачанные в кэш файлы с пакетами:

```
$ sudo apt-get clean
```

если результат вас не удовлетворит, дальше уже надо анализировать, где именно находятся самые существенные «потери». например, так:

```
$ sudo du -bd 1 / 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'sys\|proc' | sort -n
```

будет выдан отсортированный по первому столбцу список вида:

```
количество-байт /каталог
```

показывающий, сколько байт занимают файлы в том или ином каталоге.

продолжать исследования можно и глубже. например, посмотреть, сколько места занимают файлы в каталогах, расположенных внутри, например, каталога `/home`:

```
$ sudo du -bd 1 /home 2>/dev/null | sort -n
```

и ещё глубже, внутри каталога `/home/ubuntu`:

```
$ sudo du -bd 1 /home/ubuntu 2>/dev/null | sort -n
```

---

что делать с ненужными файлами, находящимися в домашнем каталоге, в общем, понятно. а вот с остальными — не так всё однозначно. простое и необдуманное удаление файлов может привести к неработоспособности как отдельных программ, так и всей системы в целом.

если какой-нибудь очень уж большой файл принадлежит установленному вами и уже не нужному пакету, то надо, конечно, не удалять файла, а деинсталлировать пакет. определить принадлежность файла/каталога пакету(-ам) можно так:

```
$ dpkg -S /путь/к/файлу/или/каталогу
```

деинсталлировать пакет можно так:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove имя-пакета
```

Comment: Спасибо, в целом понял. Видимо 10гб под Убунту это маловато, т.к. после $ sudo apt-get clean освободилось только 2%, а все файлы в home выглядят системными (начинаются с точки).

Comment: @lif3ar, начинаются с точки не «системные» файлы/каталоги, а «скрытые» (в кавычках потому, что **по умолчанию** они всего лишь не отображаются программами, предназначенными для просмотра файлов/каталогов). теоретически, у вас могут быть, например, очень «жирные» логи (`/var/log`), но, скорее всего, вы просто наустанавливали кучу пакетов, которые, возможно, вам сейчас уже и не нужны. и, да, 10 гигабайт для **десктопа** в нынешние времена — это просто «кот наплакал».